# Google Search: starring a result and refreshing -- the star is not "sticking"

Tags: google-search, google-bookmarks

I'm a long time Google Bookmarks fan and I appreciate the integration with Google Search. For some reason, I'm typing a query like "maps national parks" and clicking the star on the result "United States National Parks and Monuments Maps - Perry-Castañeda ..." to bookmark it. When I hit refresh, however, the star is empty/white. (Note that when I click the link for the page and hit my Bookmark bookmarklet the site is showing up linked, for example with the tag "maps" that I put there. Usually the star and the "maps" tag show up in search results.)

Has anyone else seen this or know how to fix it? Or is it just a matter of one Google server/cluster catching up with another?

Comment: Can you see the stared page in your bookmarks?

Comment: @Lipis: Yes I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click the star, an AJAX request is sent to the Google servers. Since Google gives no feedback of the request completing, it could be a matter of you refreshing the page too early.

It *may* be that a certain server/cluster hadn't been updated yet, but the problem should fix itself in a few seconds if that was the case.

Comment: Well, the problem hasn't gone away, even after logging in and back out. Strangely enough, if I click the link the search results and refresh, sometimes is says 2 visits (with a time stamp) in gray text, sometimes no extra gray text next to the star on one refresh, and finally, 3 visits after the third time I clicked and refreshed (after a few seconds). Perhaps Bookmarks is on a different server? I'm still baffled.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. This definitely isn't an intended behavior. Google Bookmarks doesn't have a support site, but you can [send feedback](https://spreadsheets.google.com/embeddedform?key=pPo2nzr1TywUz6Kp4cvV6NA&hl=en&gridId=0) using their form.

Comment: Not sure what to do but I guess if it persists I should send feedback. Thanks.